# How to test a function with EntityManager in play framework 2.5

Tags: java, jpa, junit, playframework

I want to test a code that is "service" level or "dao" level.

but I couldn't resolve a exception

> "No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try wrapping this call in
>   JPAApi.withTransaction, or ensure that the HTTP context is setup on
>   this thread."

This is a my code for testing by junit.

and the code what make a exception is **userService.createUser();** in function "createUser"

```
@Inject
Application application;

@Before
public void setup() {
    Module testModule = new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
        }
    };

    GuiceApplicationBuilder builder = new GuiceApplicationLoader()
            .builder(new ApplicationLoader.Context(Environment.simple()))
            .overrides(testModule);
    Guice.createInjector(builder.applicationModule()).injectMembers(this);

    Helpers.start(application);
}

@After
public void teardown() {
    Helpers.stop(application);
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void createUser() {
    running(application, () -> {
        UserService userService = application.injector().instanceOf(UserService.class);
        userService.createUser();
    });

}
```

Please, Help me to resolve the exception

thx ~

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As a thought, you might add another injected field:

```
@Inject play.db.jpa.JPAApi japApi
```

Then in your test you can call `jpaApi.withTransaction(anotherRunnableBlock);`

Answer (score 0):

probably too late for JungGyu Kim, but for other who google this issue.

I found solution for version 2.6.x, but should work also for 2.5.x.

```
package models;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import play.Application;
import play.db.jpa.JPAApi;
import play.test.Helpers;
import play.test.WithApplication;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class MyRepositoryTest extends WithApplication {

    @Override
    public Application provideApplication() {
        return Helpers.fakeApplication(Helpers.inMemoryDatabase());
    }

    JPAApi jpaApi;
    MyRepository myRepository;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        // must get instances like this, as application is created for each test
        jpaApi = app.injector().instanceOf(JPAApi.class);
        userRepository = app.injector().instanceOf(UserRepository.class);

        // no need to setup / clear DB, WithApplication create new DB for each test
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetAllEntries() {
        // insert some data first
        performNativeQuery("INSERT INTO ...");
        // call tested method
        final Stream<Entity> result = myRepository.getAllEntries();
        // perform some assertions
        assertTrue(result.count() == 1);
    }


    private void performNativeQuery(final String query) {
        jpaApi.withTransaction(em -> em.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate());
    }
}
```